# Add basic authentication to WCF Service hosted in a Windows service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, basic-authentication

How can I add basic authentication to a WCF service hosted in a Windows service?

I added a security tag to my binding, but I don't get an authentication window when I call the service url in the browser. What am I doing wrong/what am I missing?

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyDefaultBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="500" maxArrayLength="20000000" maxStringContentLength="20000000"/>  
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
       <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
   </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not get that authentication window when you just access the service helper page. The authentication is configured for service endpoint - not for helper page or WSDL (those are "separate endpoints").

Try to modify your configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="securedPages">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="None" />
      <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
    </binding>
  <customBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyDefaultBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="500" maxArrayLength="20000000" maxStringContentLength="20000000"/>  
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="securedService">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="customBinding" 
                       httpGetBindingConfiguration="securedPages" />
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpHelpPageBinding="customBinding" 
                    httpHelpPageBindingConfiguration="securedPages" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="..." behaviorConfiguration="securedService">
    ...
  </service>
</services>
```